# Is it possible to Average only certain sections of a spreadsheet with python by specifying the sections you want based on another factor?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, average, spreadsheet

I am trying to average the sea temperature for the fall and spring of each year in my data set. Imagine three columns (year/season/temp) which list things such as: 1963, FALL, 75 and continues with various years and the spring/fall season. How could I code to find the average of the temperatures that are in the fall of 1963 then the spring of 1963 then the fall of 1964 and so on all the way until 2021? My goal is to be able to show the temperature changes over time from those averages

I only have the temperature vs time scatter plot as of now and wasn't expected to have any issues but i think having multiple temperatures for each year that contradict each other (by not separating the fall/spring) is really hurting my r2 value

Comment: Are you using the `pandas` library?

Comment: Yes i usually work with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `pandas` you can perform a `groupby` on the data frame. Assuming the column names are `year`, `season` and `Temp` something like the following should work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

avg_df = df.groupby(['year','season']).agg({'Temp':[np.mean, np.std]})
avg_df.columns = ['Mean', 'STD']
```

Comment: Is there any chance you would know how to take this a step further to plot the temperature changes over time using the averages

Comment: That's a different question to which you should find examples of how to implement with an online search.